# Memory leak? Strange characters writing to file

Tags: c, linux, gnu

Good Morning. This kinda ties in to a question I posted a few days ago, this is sort of a smaller example that all ties in. When I write the contents of array b to a text file it prints a bunch of strange characters. I'm new to C, and I'm also a student so I'm trying to learn a brand new language under a time constraint.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char a[3][10] = {"Apple", "Giraffe", "Boat"};
    char b[4][10];
    
    
    
    
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++)
    {
        char tmp[15];
        sprintf(tmp, a[i]);
        
        
        sprintf(b[i], tmp);
        
    }
    
    

    FILE *f = fopen(argv[1], "wb");
    fwrite(b, 15, sizeof(b), f);
    fclose(f);

}
```

And this is a piece of the output that was written to the text file

```
Apple     Giraffe 2€Boat q€           ¶¤6€   Apple     Giraffe   Boat        H
```

Was it that I'm doing wrong that's causing this output? Should I be using memset? Malloc? Null terminators? Please help, thank you.

Comment: `sprintf(tmp, a[i]);` While this is strictly OK, you should get used to use a separate format string: `sprintf(temp,"%s",a[i]);` That will prevent weird results if you happen to have user provided input in the source string.

Comment: ^^^ That, and `sprintf(b[i], tmp);` is effectively just an expensive `strcpy(b[i], tmp);`, but with the bonus of a raging format string exploit.

Comment: A *memory leak* is when you fail to deallocate memory that you allocated.  It doesn't result in the program misbehaving, only running inefficiently (except that it may crash from memory exhaustion prematurely).  That's not the issue here; you don't even dynamically allocate any memory.

Answer (score 2):

`fwrite`'s signature is:

```
size_t fwrite(const void *restrict ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb,
              FILE *restrict stream);
```

- `size` is the size of each item to write
- `nmemb` is how many items you'd like to write

So, your call

```
fwrite(b, 15, sizeof(b), f);
```

will write `sizeof(b)` (4*10 => 40) items of size 15. That's 600 bytes and `b` is only 40 bytes. Since that's out of bounds for `b`, your program will have undefined behavior.

---

Also note that you haven't initialized `b` so it can contain just about anything. Either zero initialize it:

```
char b[4][10] = {0};
```

or set every character to a character you like:

```
char b[4][10];
memset(b, '*', sizeof b);    // #include <string.h>
```

then write `sizeof b` items of size `1`:

```
fwrite(b, 1, sizeof b, f);
```

or write `1` item of size `sizeof b`:

```
fwrite(b, sizeof b, 1, f);
```

Comment: Ohhhh, okay. Out of bounds meaning ..  thats way too many  bytes? Lol I got you, thank you.

Comment: @user11192253 Yes, exactly. It reads from memory not assigned to the `b` object.